# aws uploading files recursively except files already uploaded

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I have a need to upload files regularly from a specific directory on my computer to an on-line bucket at Amazon.  The issue is that I don't want to use up bandwidth uploading them all and over writing them.  So is there an easy way to upload them all without overwriting the files that are there already?  the command I am using is - aws s3 cp localdirectory s3:s3directory --recursive

Comment: Try aws s3 sync command

Comment: Are you doing it manually each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `aws cli s3 sync` command should be optimum for your case.

Ref:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Does this look right to you?  aws s3 sync [localdir] s3://[s3bucket]/